# How to edit an EditText from a different activity

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to do this for atleast 40 minutes now and this is my last source.

Okay so I am trying to edit an edittext from a different activity.

In first file:

(edit text with name of codeText)

```
EditText code = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.codeText);
```

(a little bit down)

```
Button tools = (Button)findViewById(R.id.toolsBtn);

    tools.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    EditText code = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.codeText);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), startNET.class);
                    intent.putExtra("code", code.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
```

In startNET (other file that I'm trying to edit the editText from):

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
final String full_code = intent.getStringExtra("code");
```

(little bit down)

```
plyerInvinc.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        String code = full_code + "\n test";
                        EditText code_text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.codeText);
                        code_text.setText(code);
                        goBackToNew(v); // this is a function for switching activities.
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
    );
```

This returns this error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JaSZ.png)

Comment: You're referncing an EditClass which doesn't exist in your activity and then you try to set text to it. So you're getting NPE.

Comment: I don't know why you would want to edit a widget in one activity while in another. When a new activity is started, the old one will be paused so no changes will be visible anyway. Wouldn't it be better to use `startActivityForResult` on the second activity and changing the `EditText` with the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referncing an EditClass which doesn't exist in your activity and then you try to set text to it. So you're getting a Null Pointer Exception.

If I understand you correctly what you should do is pass the value in:

```
plyerInvinc.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    String code = full_code + "\n test";
                    //Here pass code to the activity in which you want to set the EDitText                
                    goBackToNew(v); // this is a function for switching activities.
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
);
```

Then in onResume/onCreate (I don't know how your complete code is looking) of the activity holding R.id.codeText get the String and set it.

Comment: I have done something similar to this and it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your `EditText` which you are trying to edit is not in your current view and hence will not be accessible.

I am not sure what are you trying to achieve but if at all you want to show a value in your edit text when you return to your previous activity, try saving the value in a shared preference from current Activity and updated your `EditEtxt` in `onResume` of Activity to which it belong.